# Swift How to use Switch statement in method with 4 inputs(SENDER)

Tags: xcode, switch-statement, case

I have a problem! This code is works fine in my veiwController. But I want to move it into my struct and just call a function! This one

```
@IBOutlet weak var billTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var zeroPctButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var tenPctButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var twentyPctButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var splitNumberLabel: UILabel!


@IBAction func tipChanged(_ sender: UIButton) {
   
    
    
    billTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    
    switch sender {
    case zeroPctButton:
        zeroPctButton.isSelected = true
        tenPctButton.isSelected = false
        twentyPctButton.isSelected = false
        billTextField.endEditing(true)
    case twentyPctButton:
        tenPctButton.isSelected = false
        zeroPctButton.isSelected = false
        twentyPctButton.isSelected = true
        billTextField.endEditing(true)
    case tenPctButton:
        twentyPctButton.isSelected = false
        zeroPctButton.isSelected = false
        tenPctButton.isSelected = true
        billTextField.endEditing(true)
    default:
        print("error")
    }
```

After I try to create my method with 4 inputs, it didn't work!

```
    struct Switch {



    func switchButton(zero: UIButton, ten: UIButton, twenty: UIButton, bill: UITextField)  {
        
        switch UIButton() {
        case zero :
        zero.isSelected = true
        ten.isSelected = false
        twenty.isSelected = false
        bill.endEditing(true)
        
        case twenty :
      ten.isSelected = false
        zero.isSelected = false
       twenty.isSelected = true
     bill.endEditing(true)
        case ten:
        twenty.isSelected = false
        zero.isSelected = false
        ten.isSelected = true
        bill.endEditing(true)
    default: print("Error")
```

And when I change switch Uibutton() to zero(for example) it works with this one button!

```
    struct Switch {



    func switchButton(zero: UIButton, ten: UIButton, twenty: UIButton, bill: UITextField)  {
        
        switch zero {
        case zero :
        zero.isSelected = true
        ten.isSelected = false
        twenty.isSelected = false
        bill.endEditing(true)
        
        case twenty :
      ten.isSelected = false
        zero.isSelected = false
       twenty.isSelected = true
     bill.endEditing(true)
        case ten:
        twenty.isSelected = false
        zero.isSelected = false
        ten.isSelected = true
        bill.endEditing(true)
    default: print("Error")
```

And I tried to use nested func but didn't work for me( I also created another struct with 4 inputs which I add to code into my main struct.
And I tried to so many many things that I just can't stop! Help me understand please!

Answer (score 1):

Your original working code declared the function like this:

```
@IBAction func tipChanged(_ sender: UIButton) {
```

It had these features:

- It was a *method* (top level function) of a type.
- That type was an NSObject subclass.
- The method was marked with `@IBAction` (or `@objc`).
- The method had *one* parameter, the sender, typed as Any.

If your goal is to have buttons in your interface call this method when they are tapped, that is an Objective-C / Cocoa mechanism. So *all* of those things *must* be true.

The type of which this a method cannot be a struct; Objective-C / Cocoa, which is running the show here, cannot see Swift structs at all. And the method must be explicitly exposed to Objective-C with `@IBAction` (or `@objc`). And the method must have the right signature: no parameters, or one parameter (which is usually typed as Any or UIButton or similar), because that is the format that this mechanism can call.

Comment: So, if I wanted to create something that will be work with @IBAction I needed to have the right signature: no parameters, or one parameter (which is usually typed as Any or UIButton or similar), because that is the format that this mechanism can call. ? So I can use only one button?

Comment: I didn't say that. You can have four different buttons call into the same method, no problem, just as you did at the start. I don't quite understand what the question is at this point; it seems you had working code and you threw it away. But what was wrong with it? Your code was quite normal. Is it just that you want to move the bulk of the code into a helper function? In that case, call the helper function _from_ the working method.

Comment: Yes, my code is working, but I create another file. Where I will put all of my functions in struct, to just call them. And I created switchButton method just to call it in my IBACtion func from struct. But I didn't understand why it isn't working with 4 inputs.

Comment: Well, you say that, but you did not show any _code_ where your `tipChanged` method calls into your `switchButton` method, so I don't know what you are trying.